MAUI Compiled Bindings in ContentViews
I came across this while reading the MS documentation for compiled bindings and it has confused me now with how to do data binding on ContentViews for custom controls:

Important
Compiled bindings are disabled for any binding expressions that define the Source property. This is because the Source property is always set using the x:Reference markup extension, which can't be resolved at compile time.
In addition, compiled bindings are currently unsupported on multi-bindings.

My question concerns ContentViews where you are binding to a BindableProperty on the control.
The (recommended) approach in the documentation involves setting the binding context for the control using x:Reference as below:
<ContentView
    x:Class="LoadTimeTestingWithAsync.Controls.DriverCard"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="driverCard">
    <VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference driverCard}">
        <Label
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
            Text="Driver Details" />
        <Label
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
            Text="{Binding DriverInfo.FullName}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>

Does this mean that compiled bindings are not being used for the 2nd label bindings because the BindingContext is set on the StackLayout using x:Reference?
Or is it only when specifying source as below:
<ContentView
    x:Class="LoadTimeTestingWithAsync.Controls.DriverCard"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="driverCard">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
            Text="Driver Details" />
        <Label
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
            Text="{Binding DriverInfo.FullName, Source={x:Reference driverCard}}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>

Both are using x:Reference, but only the second is using Source.
Is it the source prop itself or the x:Reference that means compiled bindings won't be used? The blue notification sort of implies that the x:Reference is the reason with the way it is worded, but maybe if it's used to specify a BindingContext, then any binding below that will still use compiled?
I suppose following the documented examples is probably the best way to go but I just wanted to double check.

As the doc says,
Compiled bindings are disabled for any binding expressions that define the Source property. This is because the Source property is always set using the x:Reference markup extension, which can't be resolved at compile time.
So if doing bindings with x:Reference, the data bindings won't be pre-compiled (while the rest of the XAML will be pre-compiled).
By the way, I haven't seen any x:DataType set on any VisualElement, so compiled bindings won't be used anyway.
Actually, you may check the generated output or test it, e.g.
Text="{Binding WrongPropertyName, Source={x:Reference driverCard}}"  x:DataType="local:CustomView"

Like above, if you use x:Reference , even though you set the x:DataType on Label or any parent control , still there's no compile-time validation of binding expressions. You can only find data binding not working until runtime. Without x:Reference, you may see compile-time validation.

And we recommend that you follow the documented examples.

Thanks for the reply. On a page I would normally set the x:DataType to be the viewmodel to the page which would then use compiled bindings. How would I do this on ContentViews that bind to their own bindable props? It doesn't seem possible to set x:DataType on a ContentView root element like you would on a page.
Is the compiled bindings implied because they are being used on the parent page?
Just curious. I will follow the documented example

It doesn't seem possible to set x:DataType on a ContentView root element like you would on a page.  I think you could set the x:DataType such like ,<ContentView  ...              x:Name="driverCard"              x:DataType="local:CustomView"              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"              x:Class="MauiApp1.CustomView">
